# Get All User's Groups From AD via LDAP with PHP

Tags: php, search, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to grab all groups that a user belongs to using PHP.  I am able to grab all of the groups that are listed in the memberof attribute, but not the user's inherited groups.

I've tried modifying the code to also do an ldap_search for the group name/samaccount name but I've not been successful in searching for the group's memberof attribute.

Below is the code that I'm using.

```
$checkDn=$this->setDn(true); 
$results[0]=$attribute; 

// We need to search for this user in order to get their entry.
$this->result=@ldap_search($this->connection,$checkDn,$this->getUserIdentifier()."=$uname",$results);
$info=ldap_get_entries($this->connection, $this->result);

// Only one entry should ever be returned(no user will have the same uid) 
$entry=ldap_first_entry($this->connection, $this->result);

if(!$entry){
 $this->ldapErrorCode=-1;
 $this->ldapErrorText="Couldn't find user";
 return false; // Couldn't find the user...
}

// Get all the member DNs
if(!$values=@ldap_get_values($this->connection,$entry,$attribute)){
 $this->ldapErrorCode=ldap_errno($this->connection);
 $this->ldapErrorText=ldap_error($this->connection);
 return false; // No matching attributes 
}

// Return an array containing the attributes. 
return $values;
```

Here is a sample group that they belong to.

```
CN=Business Operations,OU=Groups,OU=Operations,OU=Corporate,OU=company name,DC=website,DC=com
```

Thanks for any assistance with this!